# How to integrate remember me in ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

window.localStorage['uname'] = Username;
window.localStorage['pass'] = password;

Hi, I am trying to save my user name and password permanently for remember me functionality. I am using the above code for that but when I terminate the app then re-open it the local storage is getting drained. How can I save the login credential?

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage is persistent. It will not be deleted till the user delets the Application. Do you maybe define the localStorage-Values at another line of code to `0` or `null`? The issue has to be inside your code. Please provide a full code snippet or more Code.

I just tried it:

```
localStorage.username = username;
localstorage.password = password;
```

closed the application, re-opened it, the data is still there.

Comment: with closing i meant terminating the application.

Answer (score 0):

I personally inject `$window` into my controller and services to access  localStorage and to set my variable `$window.localStorage[key] = value`

And to get my variable just access it like this: `$window.localStorage[key]`

However, storing your login & password within your app is not a very good idea. Remember me shall be implemented on server side.

Comment: why shouldn't that be a good idea? Tell me how to inject the localStorage from the outside?

Comment: Storing passwords and usernames on locally, accessible devices is hardly ever a good idea. And I am sure you would store as plain text, right? So, that's a huge security risk to your users and you run the risk of damages incurring.